# How to address a question asking about a bugged feature in a product?

Tags: discussion

I recently found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855363/excecute-program-on-windows-bash) about WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux, currently in beta) asking about support for 32bits binary.

Currently, WSL doesn't support them, and the issue is logged in their github and UserVoice websites.

As of now, the only answer to the question is : "You have to wait until the devs fix this behaviour".

What should be the correct way to handle the question ? Answer "You can't do it for now" ? Flag it to be put on hold ? Wait until the devs implement the feature, then answer it ?

Comment: These aren't really good questions for Stack Overflow. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company. The question asker should really be on UserVoice.

Comment: It is not the only answer, somebody can *know* why this restriction exists.  Finding experts that know the intricate details was certainly one of SO's goals.  Well, originally anyway.  You can post something like that as a comment.  They are going to wait for a very long time.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, adding support for 32 bits binaries in the kernel of an OS embeded inside Windows 10 seems like an extremely non-trivial task that would be better answered on the developpers github rather than on an SO post imo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say just answer that it isn't possible for now and link to the github and UserVoice websites in your answer. Once the devs implement the feature you can come back to the answer and update it.

Just because the answer to a question is that it's not possible for now I don't see a reason to close it.

However, if it's purely a support question along the lines of "does this product support this feature" and not really a programming question then they should rather ask the manufacturer and the question would be off-topic for SO.

Comment: The question in itself is good, it's just that after a bit of research we found in the comments the feature was not supported

Comment: @Aserre Could you maybe add a link to the question? To me it makes a difference if the OP is trying to do something and then you figure out that what they want to do is currently not possible because of the lack of 32bit support (which the devs are going to fix) or whether the question is pretty much just wanting to know if or when 32 bit binaries will be supported. In the first case I would say an answer is fine.

Comment: I'v added the link to the question in my OP. To me the question falls in the 1rst category.

Comment: @Aserre Yep, that's exactly the case I was talking about. Looks fine to me.