# Replace "Duplicate" with "Resolved Elsewhere" as a close reason

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

Spurred by the commented feedback under [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417569/2943403) to [Question Close Reasons project - Introduction and Feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417475/2943403), I'd like to see the term "**Duplicate**" retired. In its place, I'd like to see the less inflammatory "**Resolved Elsewhere**" term which expresses the intent to help the asker find a solution.

[image]

<sub>I'm not too fussed about whether the subtext is retained; think of it as a starting point.</sub>

Regarding the current terminology:

1. "This question has been asked before" is sometimes inaccurate when a newer, better page is used to close an older page and
2. the term "Duplicate" indicates identicality which is not always the case and has been a highly contentious topic for years

I am aware that in fringe cases where the same user asks the same question twice, it is possible to close the second question with the first question -- even if the first doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer.  I'm not so worried about this because 1. this represents a miniscule portion of daily uses of this close reason and 2. the users that are here frequently enough to catch such a scenario are already well-aware that this close reason will do the job.  On the other hand, closers could always opt to use a custom close reason as well -- this is always a bad question, no reason to upvote these types of questions.

Potential Benefits:

- This change may help to steer contributors to be more conscientious about how and why they are voting to close. Ideally, they should be endeavoring to serve the asker and Stack Overflow simultaneously (not serving one at the expense of the other).
- This will pave the way to understanding that it may be reasonable to upvote and close questions. For instance, it may be a very good signpost because it represents a new way of encountering the problem or it actually isolates the problem better than the canonical.

Comment: _This represents <1% of daily uses of this close reason_ Citation needed there. I certainly use it for that a lot, it's a situation that occurs quite often (and is hard to trace, most of these duplicates are deleted so SEDE queries tend to go wrong). Oh, and replacing it with something vague like "a minuscule proportion" doesn't mean we don't need to talk about how miniscule (if it even is miniscule)

Comment: "fringe cases where the same user asks the same question twice" that might be addressed in the proposed description via "or is an exact duplicate" since the proposal unties the "duplicate" term from the close reason already.

Comment: @Oleg yes, I considered appending that as well.  However, I decided against it because it would then heap together questions that are always "bad" with questions that might not be.  The more I think about it, I think the "blatant dupe by the same user/company" (we've seen teams ask from multiple accounts), should be closed as a custom reason that should unconditionally contribute to a question ban.  Where as, asking an upvoted question that is Resolved Elsewhere should not count toward a question ban.  What do you think?

Comment: @mickmackusa I would not be against a separate "exact duplicate" close reason for those, yeah. It could even be a community-specific one to ease the company into endorsing it. IIRC, that's how the dupe close reason was initiallu called, isn't it?

Comment: "Resolved"... too specific. Answering is what we do, it is the terminology you find everywhere on the site so I don't know why all of a sudden we need to break from the norm. Sometimes that answer contains a resolve for a problem, sometimes it contains merely information. In multiple answers, if necessary to cover all the bases. So why not "answered elsewhere"? Not hip enough?

Comment: Support... // + When closing as "blatant Dupe by same User/Company/Team", couldn't the Dupe be deleted "a bit quicker" than having to wait for 30 days until 'Roomba' will eventually delete the Dupe, and for small Tags, often relying on just 1 Downvote...? When monitoring some (small) Tag, it is "frustrating" to have to endure for 1 whole month the "Sight" of 2 exact same Threads by the same User... Example: ([Original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71562492/) / [Blatant Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71588158/))

Comment: @Gimby In the eyes of the new asker, it is insufficient to close a question because another page "has answers".  The new asker is absolutely desiring a resolution to their specific question.  If the target does not "resolve" their question, we expect them to edit their question to isolate how/why the target did not resolve their question so that it can be potentially reopened.  I realize we are quibbling over semantics, but receiving an "answer" and receiving a "resolution" mean two different things (to me) and the difference is the perceived quality.

Comment: @mickmackusa not "has answers", but "is answered". That has always been the definition for a closing as a dupe, because the question *is answered* somewhere else.

Comment: I _really_ like this; I'm not going to say that the wording is perfect by any means, but I love the idea of changing the language to be something that's more representative of what we mean by "duplicate" here on Stack Exchange (ie. that it doesn't always mean "exact same question").